# How to stop Java application executed from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Let's say I have Java console application with endless loop in main function. When I execute it from the DOS window:

```
java MyBuggyProgram
```

I can press Ctrl+C to stop it. How can I stop it, when I use Run command from Eclipse (Windows)? The program is not listed in the Task Manager. Ctrl+C in the Console window doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On bottom right of eclipse you will see one red icon. You can click on it. It pops up confirmation message. Just accept it.

Answer (score 4):

Click on the terminate icon (red square) in the console view.

Comment: this stops only the current process, if you started more processes before, they will persist running

Answer (score 4):

The process **has** to be in the list in the Task Manager. Check for processes using large share of CPU. Most likely name is[image] javaw.exe

Answer (score 1):

go to:

> Windows -> Show View -> Other... -> Android -> Devices

and press the STOP red button

Comment: Your device will be listed.  Click the row with the package name. Stop button will then appear.  Click it.

Answer (score 1):

[image: **You can assign any shortcut key to terminate **]

You can assign any shortcut key to terminate

Answer (score 1):

In the console, click on red icon(Note: It turns red only after starting the program, else it remains gray/translucent)
[image: Eclipse Console View for reference]

Answer (score 1):

run below command  in CMD

```
netstat -ano |findstr <-port no->
```

you will get pid (process id) for the running application

```
taskkill /f /pid <-your pid->
```

Comment: Like this solution, as it also allows a soft kill, without option w/o option /f, and so debug a shutdown handler.